# Proplot documentation for custom width subplots example doesn't run (refwidth throws error)

Tags: python, matplotlib

Using proplot-0.9.5, the example code on https://proplot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/subplots.html (see below) gives an unexpected keyword argument 'refwidth' (see below also) error when trying to make custom scaled subplots.

Does anyone know why this doesn't work? Proplot does everything else I ask of it without a problem.

Code to reproduce the error:

```
import proplot as pplt
pplt.rc.update(grid=False, titleloc='uc', titleweight='bold', titlecolor='red9')

# Change the reference subplot width
suptitle = 'Effect of subplot width on figure size'
for refwidth in ('3cm', '5cm'):
    fig, axs = pplt.subplots(ncols=2, refwidth=refwidth,)
    axs[0].format(title=f'refwidth = {refwidth}', suptitle=suptitle)

# Change the reference subplot aspect ratio
suptitle = 'Effect of subplot aspect ratio on figure size'
for refaspect in (1, 2):
    fig, axs = pplt.subplots(ncols=2, refwidth=1.6, refaspect=refaspect)
    axs[0].format(title=f'refaspect = {refaspect}', suptitle=suptitle)

# Change the reference subplot
suptitle = 'Effect of reference subplot on figure size'
for ref in (1, 2):  # with different width ratios
    fig, axs = pplt.subplots(ncols=3, wratios=(3, 2, 2), ref=ref, refwidth=1.1)
    axs[ref - 1].format(title='reference', suptitle=suptitle)
for ref in (1, 2):  # with complex subplot grid
    fig, axs = pplt.subplots([[1, 2], [1, 3]], refnum=ref, refwidth=1.8)
    axs[ref - 1].format(title='reference', suptitle=suptitle)

pplt.rc.reset()
```

The error:

```
> TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'refwidth'
```